# WEBGL. Как правильно использовать текстуру для передачи данных в шейдер

Tags: webgl, текстура

Использую текстуру для передачи данных в вершинный шейдер. Данных может быть много, поэтому юниформ массив скорее всего не подойдет из-за ограничения по его размеру, либо его придется обновлять для каждого draw-call. В текстуре хранятся данные для нескольких draw-calls, **каждая строка - для своего draw call.**

Проблема, предположительно, в том, что адресация в текстуре происходит в пределах от 0 до 1, а не точно по пикселям, что, вкупе с **NEAREST** интерполяцией в текстуре, приводит к неточной адресации по вертикали - в некоторых draw calls используются данные из соседних строк.

Пример кода:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, points_in_line, total_lines, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, control_points_array);

for( var i = 0; i <= total_lines; i++ ){

    gl.uniform1f( this.line_id, i/total_lines); // Перевод целочисленных индексов в размерность 0-1 текстуры

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, count, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    gl.drawElements( gl.POINTS, count, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );

}
```

```
uniform float line_id;
vec4 first_point = texture2D(data_texture, vec2( 0.0, line_id) );
```

Существует ли способ гарантированно получить из текстуры нужное значение, как из двумерного массива, или будет правильно отойти от использования единой текстуры для всех draw calls, а вместо этого обновлять данные в юниформ массиве для каждого draw call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же помните, что центры пикселей в текстуре будут отстоять на полпикселя? Т.е. при размере текстуры 2х2, ваш код выдаст `0.5` и `1.0`, а настоящие центры будут на `0,25` и `0,75`. Т.е. вы сэмплируете края пикселей. Отсюда, могут быть и погрешности ..

Пример для тестуры размером 8х8:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот это очень дельное замечание, спасибо.
Как думаете, если к полученному индексу пикселя прибавлять (1 / tex_width / 2), это поможет стабильно получать нужные значения? Ведь как-то же используют текстуры для передачи данных.

Comment: Пробуйте. Судя по коду, должно быть все чисто, но мб еще надо генерацию мипмапов отключить, и мб еще указать ЛОД сэмплирования в шейдере типа -999.